# Unable to access result of $addFields in $lookup in MongoDB Aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I have a aggregation function in which there are nested lookups with pipeline.
In one of the pipeline I have the following -

```
{
 "$addFields": {
  "ids": {
     "$split": ["$id", ","]
   }
  }
},
{
 "$lookup": {
   "from": 'collection2',
   "let": {"new_id": "$ids"},
    "pipeline": [
     { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
           "$in": ["$ID", "$$new_id"]
         }  
        } 
      }
     ],
    "as": 'groups'
   }
  }
```

In the above pipeline **addFields is splitting the comma separated** value in **"id"** and **adding it to an array** named **"ids"**.

This **"ids"** I am using it in lookup below to find the data from other collection using **"$in"**.

But I am getting this error in **MongoDB Compass** - **$in requires an array as a second argument, found: null**.

I tried the same by using just this pipeline in a separate aggregation pipeline in Compass where I am getting the results properly but when I include the same in my nested lookup pipeline its not working and giving the above error.

Is it because of nesting or any local variable or any other issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error message `$in requires an array as a second argument, found: null` is indicating that there was a value found, and it was null.

If no value was found at all, the error would have been `"$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing"`

The mostly likely problem is that one or more documents in the collection don't have an `id` field, so the `$split` returns null.

To work around this, you might use the `$ifNull` operator to return an empty array when `$split` returns null, like:

```
{"$addFields": {
  "ids": {
     "$ifNull":[
          {"$split": ["$id", ","]},
          []
     ]
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Understood the problem. Your solution worked.

Comment: One correction is that to check Null "$ifNull" is used. I think there's a typo mistake.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.